# Using a parent environment to access child

Tags: r

I'm attempting to create a hierarchy of environments, where I have one main environment which contains a variety of other environments which could then contain other environments (and so on).

I create the environment and its child like this:

```
parentEnv <- new.env()
childEnv <- new.env(parentEnv)
```

We can see that the parent and child were created:

```
> childEnv
<environment: 0x000000000e811208>
> parentEnv
<environment: 0x000000000d9e2440>
```

However, I then check the child's parent and it tells me its the R_Global. (This isn't actually surprising as I was able to access it directly). Does `new.env(parent)` not do what I think it does?

```
> parent.env(childEnv)
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

That's fine, I then set my child's parent as `parent.env(childEnv) <- parentEnv` (though the R docs says this is 'dangerous' and could be become deprecated, I wanted to try it anyway).

> parent.env(childEnv) <- parentEnv

```
> childEnv
<environment: 0x000000000e811208>
> parent.env(childEnv)
<environment: 0x000000000d9e2440>
```

We now see that the child's parent is parentEnv! Everything should be great, right...?

```
> parentEnv$childEnv
NULL
> with(parentEnv, childEnv)
<environment: 0x000000000e811208>
```

I can't access it with $. Though I can using the 'with' notation. What's going on here? Am not understand how environments work in R?

Comment: You might want to read http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html for an introduction to environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question about `with`: The argument `parentEnv` in `with(parentEnv, childEnv)` is being ignored, and the object `childEnv` is found because it *belongs* in R_GlobalEnv. You can see that running any of these:

```
eval(childEnv)
evalq(childEnv)
with(new.env(), childEnv)
```

The environment where an (environment) object belongs is not necessarily its parent environment.

If you want to set not only the parent environment of children but also the environment where they belong to `parentEnv`, I suggest one of this two options:

```
parentEnv <- new.env()
parentEnv$childEnv1 <- new.env(parent=parentEnv)
evalq(childEnv2 <- new.env(), parentEnv)
```

Note that they give the same result:

```
parentEnv                        # <environment: 0x0000000007ec0c18>
parent.env(parentEnv$childEnv1)  # <environment: 0x0000000007ec0c18>
parent.env(parentEnv$childEnv2)  # <environment: 0x0000000007ec0c18>
```

EDIT: I've changed `local` to `evalq`, since they give the same result and the latter is more intuitive. Thanks @hadley.

Comment: Thank you very much, `parentEnv$childEnv1 <- new.env(parent=parentEnv)` gave me exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I think `local()` is a really bad suggestion here, since it's so difficult to understand what it does.

Comment: @hadley, I've changed `local` to `evalq`; the latter is better in this case, isn't it?

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft yes, definitely.

Answer (score 0):

You doesn't actually seem like you are passing the `parent` argument when you make `childEnv`. You are relying on R type-matching the argument to `parent` which doesn't seem to work here. At the moment (and I am guessing) R is positional matching your environment to the `hash` argument and because it is not logical it is silently dropping it. Instead try this:

```
parentEnv <- new.env()
childEnv <- new.env( parent = parentEnv )

parentEnv
#<environment: 0x1078dde60>
parent.env( childEnv )
#<environment: 0x1078dde60>
```

I assume the fact that it didn't work as you had in your OP is something to do with the fact that `new.env()` is a `.Primitive` function. From the help manual for `?.Primitive`:

> The advantage of `.Primitive` over `.Internal` functions is the potential efficiency of argument passing, and that positional matching can be used where desirable, e.g. in `switch`. For more details, see the ‘*R Internals Manual*’

Comment: I tried your suggestion and you are correct regarding the R type-matching failing me. I suppose it is best practice to always specify which type you are passing in.

Comment: Huh? The first argument to `new.env()` is `hash`, not parent. Also, `new.env()` is _not_ a primitive function.

Comment: @hadley Thanks for your comment. I know `hash` is the first argument. Did you read my answer? `hash` is optional so if you don't supply a logical argument to `new.env` I thought that would get ignored and R would match the supplied environment (`parentEnv` in the OPs case) to the `parent` argument. This doesn't happen. R just seems to ignore `parentEnv` (e.g. `new.env(parentEnv)`. 2. Yes thanks - I got muddled between .Internal and .Primitive - some of the environment functions *are* *primitive*, e.g. `baseenv()`.

Comment: I think you need to check your understand of R's function calling semantics, e.g. http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#function-arguments

Comment: @hadley I'm not really arguing with you, but I would *expect* that R *should* throw an error such as `"Error in new.env(parentEnv) : hash should be of type logical"`. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: @SimonO101 It would be nice for it throw an error, but most R functions don't do a very good job of checking the types of their input.